# An alternative to the `set()` function to retrieve a set of unique email?

Tags: python, database-design, google-cloud-datastore, nosql

I have a python script used to send email to people,
but don't want to email people more than once. I currently use a Python `set` to retrieve unique email addresses, but I want my solution to be scalable and persistent.

I have something like (30K) email addresses, and I am interested to know if this is doable easily in Google-datastore? Would that be an expensive operation ?

Comment: The _"best solution"_ is rather opinion based, or at least dependent of your needs. But as a starting point, I would say you need to store your (customer?) data into some table of a relational database, and retrieve the _set_ of email using a query like `SELECT DISTINCT email FROM customers` -- depending your data size, _sqlite_ might be perfectly suited for that task.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux would you load the whole set of customers to a set once and then not query the db each time ? how should I know, if the items are not too many for my RAM (how much is too much to store in Set in RAM)

Comment: When you query your DB, you get back a cursor that allow you to fetch your rows one by one. So you don't need to store all your data at once in main memory. But as I said before, all of this is rather speculative as I don't really know your needs (for example: you talk about "scalability". But of how many email are we talking about ? Hundred ? Thousands ? Billions ? Are you sending the same email to all your customers ? Have you some other constraints ?)

Comment: @SylvainLeroux thousands (30K) and  I am interested to know if this solution is doable easily in Google-datastore or would it be better to use relational database . I

Comment: I took the liberty to update your question according to your last comments -- and to remove the most subjective part of it. I've done my best given the little time I have now. I will cast a reopen vote. Feel free to revert that edit and/or edit further your question if you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from GAE 1.7.4, [GQL](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/apis/gql/gql_reference#grammar) supports `SELECT DISTINCT ...` queries so you could use that to get back the set of ... well ... *distinct* email address for your customers.

Please note that modern (how much modern?) versions of GQL have support for the `GROUP BY` clause too, if that suits your needs best.

Comment: can you give me an example how to create a user profile table using GQL with email as primary key and description and number of times been emailed (int) and then a an example how to insert one row to it using python?

Comment: @MedyaGh - how can this possibly be an accepted answer? Your question is 100% opinion-based, with dozens (if not hundreds) of possible answers. You're marking one of these as an answer? I don't see how. Not only that, but this answer suggests a RAM-based solutoin initially, which isn't durable. Again, accepting this answer makes zero sense.

Comment: @DavidMakogon fair enough, if you have a better answer, please provide it, it was the only answer.

Comment: @MedyaGh - I think you missed my point: There is no better answer. There is no objective answer to be had. It's subjective. Opinion-based. And not a fit for StackOverflow. I can easily rattle off a dozen perfectly suitable answers, each with a completely different data store. None of them would qualify as "the" right answer. And choosing the only posted opinion, as accepted answer, doesn't help at all.

Comment: @David Thank you for your comments. By re-reading the original question I can only agree with you. I realized now that I've answered according to the various comments of the OP: as I understood it, it was about retrieving a set of unique emails from a pool of something like of 30K records. Still in the comments, the op was asking if there was an alternative using Google datastore to retrieve that set without relying on the Python `set()` function.

Comment: @David Obviously, that does not match with the question as it was originally asked by the OP. I've took the liberty to edit the question to reflect that. About "scalability" the OP expected needs are not that high that a RAM based solution will not work. But definitively not persistent. I've removed that part.